# ORM: Sequelize: Add Not Equal Constraint for Two Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, orm, sequelize.js

I have a `following` table. I don't want user to follow himself so I want to add a `CHECK` constraint.

[image]

For example, if this is inserted, I want database to throw an error.

```
{
   userID: 1,
   followingID: 1,
}
```

I can check with Javascript if userID and followingID are equal but I want database to check it.

My MYSQL version is 8.0.17 so I think it is possible to create this constraint with SQL. How can I add this constraint with Sequelize?

Comment: Can you explain a bit better? You want a certain column to be unique, or a combination of columns to be unique? are we talking just about "following" table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## There is two solution

#### 1. Using Model wise validation and adding check constraint in database manually:

Model wise validation:

```
const FollowingModel = sequelize.define("following", {
     userId: {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          // .. other configuration like `allowNull`
     },
     followingId: {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          // .. other configuration like `allowNull`
     }
}, {
    validate: {
         userShouldNotFollowSelf : function() {
             if(this.userId === this.followingId) {
                 throw Error("User should not follow self") // Use any custom error class if your application has such class.
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Beware this will allow you create entry in database which does not maintain this constraint.

It is just ORM's application layer check that, this application won't allow any entry where `userId` and `followingId` is not same.

Mysql database layer [check constraint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html).

```
CREATE TABLE `following`
(
  `userId` INT NOT NULL,
  `followingId` INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `no_self_following` CHECK (`userId` <> `followingId`)
  -- other properties and foreign key constraints.
);
```

It will ensure that, no such entry inserted where `userId` and `followingId` is same.

#### 2. Declaring constraint in sequelize query interface.

This require to declare your model using query interfaces [addConstraint](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/query-interface.js%7EQueryInterface.html#instance-method-addConstraint) as follows

```
sequelize.getQueryInterface().addConstraint("following", ['userId'], {
    type: 'check',
    name: "no_self_following"
    where: {
        userId: {
            [Sequelize.Op.ne]: Sequelize.col("followingId")
        }
    }
});
```

Run this while all database model is been synced correctly. It will add database level constraint.

Which one to use ?

Approach #1 is more efficient. It is checking within the application without going into the database call, Makes your database less busy.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks.

Comment: Update: this answer needs a minor update.
query interface `addConstraint` is updated in the newer version of Sequelize. You need to pass fields to the options object.
queryInterface.addConstraint('following', {
  fields: ['userId'],
  type: 'check',
  name: 'no_self_following',
});

Comment: @Johnson Could you please accept the question first ?

Comment: accepted. Thanks. Could you update addConstraint params?